# Allow one grid item to scroll with fixed header and sidebar

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout with two columns and two rows. A sticky left nav, a sticky header, and content that will live in the bottom right corner of the grid.

What I have now is nearly there, but I would like the `.content` div to use scroll when content extends beyond the screen. I thought I would be able to just use `overflow: auto`, but that isn't working. Is what I have close?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 55px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 20vh auto;
  grid-template-areas: "nav header" "nav content";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  height: 1000px; // This is dynamic
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="nav">Side nav</div>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>title</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seanyesmunt/hh5vxa0e/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For `overflow: auto` to work (i.e., for scrollbars to render) browsers need a trigger. This trigger is usually a height / width limitation that forces an overflow condition, which launches the scrollbars.

Trigger conditions vary among browsers. They also vary among CSS technologies, such as flex, grid and block layouts.

In this particular case, there are several logical places to establish an overflow condition, but none of them work.

1. You could target the grid item, as you have tried:

   ```
   .content {
      height: 1000px
      overflow: auto;
   }
   ```

   But it doesn't work. No scrollbar appears on the fluid item.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 55px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 20vh auto;
  grid-template-areas: "nav header" 
                       "nav content";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="nav">Side nav</div>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>title</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
```

2. You could target the row itself, as I tested:

   ```
   .page {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 55px 1000px;
   }

   .content {
      overflow: auto;
   }
   ```

   But that doesn't work either. Still no scrollbar on the fluid item.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 55px 1000px;
  grid-template-columns: 20vh auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav header"
    "nav content";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="nav">Side nav</div>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>title</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
```

3. So I targeted a *child* of the grid item. DING DING DING! That worked.

   No need for fixed positioning. No need for sticky positioning. This works across all browsers that support Grid Layout.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 55px calc(100vh - 55px);  /* height limitation on second row */
  grid-template-columns: 20vh auto;
  grid-template-areas: "nav header" 
                       "nav content";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;                          /* overflow condition on parent */
}

article {
  height: 1000px;                          /* height set on child; triggers scroll */
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="nav">Side nav</div>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <article><!-- new section for content -->
      <h1>title</h1>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hh5vxa0e/2/)

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution; well explained and implemented! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Browser support is not 100%, but what about actually using sticky instead of fixed positioning? (now tested in Chrome) You won't have to deal with hard-coded margins.

One of the issues you'll still have to deal with, what to do when the content in your sidebar (`.nav > div`) Is higher than your viewport.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 55px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 3.5rem auto;
  grid-template-areas: "nav header" "nav content";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: blue;
}

.nav > div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: grey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 3.5rem;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="nav">
    <div>Side nav</div>
  </div>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>title</h1>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: I likeit, and there are polyfills to emulate position:sticky;
https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky

Comment: Works well. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for fixed or sticky positioning. With a few adjustments to the CSS and HTML, the layout works as desired.

Comment: @Michael_B  improved an answer based on what Lakindu wrote. I don't even know what the actual requirements are. I would rather take your answer as a fallback because imho it's often desirable to have a scrollbar over the whole window(in your example the scroll only works when my pointer is on the red area). It can also be a bit ugly in some browsers.

Comment: I think the intention is for the scrollbar to exist only on the fluid grid area. The other areas are supposed to be fixed. The layout already had a scrollbar on the entire window (just remove `overflow: hidden` on the `body` element).

Comment: Yes. This solution worked, but I would much rather have the scrollbar start at the scrollable content, below the header. @Michael_B 's answer is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I have included the change log to see where the code needs to be change in order to get an understanding. Also the full code snippet is available below. Hope this is what you expect.

**Change log**

*Remove `body { overflow: hidden; }`

*Change `.page { grid-template-columns: 3.5rem auto; }`

*Added

```
.nav { position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom:0;}
```

*Added

```
.header {  position: fixed;
      margin-left: 3.5rem;
      width: 100%;
      height: 3.5rem; }
```

Full Code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 55px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 3.5rem auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav header"
    "nav content";
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: blue;

}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5rem;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="nav">Side nav</div>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>title</h1>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Not quite. I want the header and side nav to be sticky. And only scroll the bottom right `.content` div

Comment: "position: fixed" for side nav and header would do. Let me check

Comment: check now @seanyesmunt

Comment: Hmm that's closer. I feel like messing with margins shouldn't be needed with css grid?

I would like to extend the styling on the content div and keep basic grid styling on the nav/header (if possible). I'll play around with what you have some more. Another thing I would like to avoid is having the scroll bar extend to the top of the screen. Ideally it would start at the top of the content div

Comment: Scroll bar is extended due to fixed height provided in the .content. And I think "rem" units are responsive as well. I had to change   grid-template-columns because it was not responsive with the given units. Do you need more support?

Comment: I had to play with margins because both side bar and header bar should be fixed. And they overlap, to avoid it, i have used "rem" units which is responsive anywhere. Maybe there can be a better solution