# html/css grid layout with a fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a fixed header and footer using a grid layout. I want the header to always be on the top and the footer to always be on the bottom of the viewport. The "content" should push down from the top and push up from the bottom to offset the header/footer content. And the scroll bars should scroll the content area.

When I apply `position: fixed` and then `top: 0` to the header or `bottom: 0` to the footer, it breaks the grid layout.

This is what I have tried so far:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.div5 {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.parent div {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.div3 {
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

.div4,
.div5 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="div1">a</div>
    <div class="div2">b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br
      />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br
      />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br
      />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br
      />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br />b<br /></div>
    <div class="div3">c</div>
    <div class="div4">d</div>
    <div class="div5">e</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any element with `position: fixed` is no longer a grid element. You can create a `position: fixed` `<header>` and `<footer>` _outside_ the `display: grid` `<main>`.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258653/fixed-header-in-css-grid/52226523

Comment: The footer on that one is not fixed to the bottom of the viewport.